# Oracle left outer join, only want the null values

Tags: sql, oracle, join, outer-join

I'm working on a problem with two tables.  Charge and ChargeHistory.  I want to display a selection of columns from both tables where either the matching row in ChargeHistory has a different value and/or date from Charge or if there is no matching entry in ChargeHistory at all.

I'm using a left outer join declared using the ansi standard and while it does show the rows correctly where there is a difference, it isn't showing the null entries.

I've read that there can sometimes be issues if you are using the WHERE clause as well as the ON clause.  However when I try and put all the conditons in the ON clause the query takes too long > 15 minutes (so long I have just cancelled the runs).

To make things worse both tables use a three part compound key.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why the null values are being left out?

```
    SELECT values...
    FROM bcharge charge
    LEFT OUTER JOIN chgHist history
    ON charge.key1 = history.key1 AND charge.key2 = history.key2 AND charge.key3 = history.key3 AND charge.chargeType = history.chargeType
    WHERE charge.chargeType = '2'
      AND (charge.value <> history.value OR charge.date <> history.date)
    ORDER BY key1, key2, key
```

Comment: Thank you guys, looks like the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to explicitly select the null values:

```
 SELECT values...
    FROM bcharge charge
    LEFT OUTER JOIN chgHist history
    ON charge.key1 = history.key1 AND charge.key2 = history.key2 AND charge.key3 = history.key3 AND charge.chargeType = history.chargeType
    WHERE charge.chargeType = '2'
      AND ((charge.value <> history.value or history.value is null) OR (charge.date <> history.date or history.date is null))
    ORDER BY key1, key2, key
```

Answer (score 1):

You can explicitly look for a match in the `where`.  I would recommend looking at one of the keys used for the `join`:

```
SELECT . . . 
FROM bcharge charge LEFT OUTER JOIN
     chgHist history
     ON charge.key1 = history.key1 AND charge.key2 = history.key2 AND
        charge.key3 = history.key3 AND charge.chargeType = history.chargeType
WHERE charge.chargeType = '2' AND
      (charge.value <> history.value OR charge.date <> history.date OR history.key1 is null)
ORDER BY key1, key2, key;
```

The expressions `charge.value <> history.value` change the `left outer join` to an `inner join` because `NULL` results will be filtered out.

Answer (score 1):

A `WHERE` clause filters the data returned by a join. Therefore when your inner table has null data for a particular column, the corresponding rows get filtered out based on your specified condition. That is why you should move that logic to the `ON` clause instead.

For the performance issues, you could consider adding indexes on the columns used for joining and filtering.

Comment: I wish I could add indexes, however SELECT statements are the limit of my privileges on the database.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this site, it will be very helpful for you, visual illustration of all the join statements with code samples

[blog.codinghorror.com](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/)

**Quoted of the relevant info in the above link:**

```
SELECT * FROM TableA
LEFT OUTER JOIN TableB
ON TableA.name = TableB.name
```

**Sample output:**

```
id  name       id    name
--  ----       --    ----
1   Pirate     2     Pirate
2   Monkey     null  null
3   Ninja      4     Ninja
4   Spaghetti  null  null
```

**Left outer join**

produces a complete set of records from Table A, with the matching records (where available) in Table B. If there is no match, the right side will contain null

Comment: Please include the relevant parts or a brief explanation of the contents of the linked article in case the link goes dead.

Answer (score 0):

For any field from an outer joined table used in the `where clause` you must also permit an `IS NULL` option for that same field, otherwise you negate the effect of the outer join and the result is the same as if you had used an inner join.

```
SELECT
      *
FROM bcharge charge
      LEFT OUTER JOIN chgHist history
                  ON charge.key1 = history.key1
                        AND charge.key2 = history.key2
                        AND charge.key3 = history.key3
                        AND charge.chargeType = history.chargeType
WHERE charge.chargeType = '2'
      AND (
            (charge.value <> history.value OR history.value IS NULL)
           OR 
            (charge.date <> history.date OR history.date IS NULL)
          )
ORDER BY
      key1, key2, key3
```

---

Edit: Appears that this is the same query structure used by Rene above, so treat this one as in support of that please.